# My design view in content_main is always empty. When I try to drop a button or a textView, it will shrink to the top left corner

Tags: android, android-studio, design-view

I am trying to drop some components into content_main. But every time I drop it, it will shrink to the top left corner. No matter how much I expand it, it just does not show up.

[image]

I tried the following suggestions:

1. Restarting my Android Studio
2. add "Base" to parent in the styles.xml
3. Invalidate cache/restart

Here is the code in my content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

There is no error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to delete this line

```
android:visibility="gone"
```

also you need to correct your button alignment a bit

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably because ConstraintLayout `android:visibility="gone"`

Comment: Damn, you're fast... 

Comment: Haha, hope i helped!